# Windows Server 2003 C: partition - managing

Tags: windows-server-2003

Our admin put a 12gb C: partition on the 64-bit Windows 2003 server that hosts my asp.net and classic asp apps.

Is that sufficient? What can I safely move off to an external disk (service pack files, etc?)

Comment: Have you considered asking the admin to resize the partition, or moving your apps to another partition?

Comment: I recently got a call at 1 am from an ISP that ran a server out of space. They also had only 12GB. I then went through  number of their servers, and found several more that were on the cusp of running out of space.

Comment: Yes, but you should make it your admin's problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will fit but I wouldn't reccomend it.  Over time that will fill up rather quickly.  With disk space so inexpensive I would make it at least 30 GB.

Comment: I agree at least 30GB to 60GB, 12GB is way to small. If the server isn't in full production yet you may want to consider reformatting and partitioning the drive to accommodate 60GB.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, Win2k3 server will fit in a 12GB partition. You'll have to be very careful not to put extra "stuff" on there, as it simply wont fit. But it could work.

I'd highly recommend expanding the partition; use a gparted live CD if necessary to resize and move and adjacent partitions.

Answer (score 1):

When you say external disk to you mean a permanently attached disk i.e. D: or E:?  If so then:

1. You can move your web sites and virtual directories and re-point to their new locations in IIS. Create new web site or virtual dir and choose a path on D:/E: drive and move your web site files.
2. Run disk cleanup util from accessories and see what it can do for you
3. You can use cleanup methods to remove old Windows patches and service packs from inside c:\windows but this means you can't uninstall those (which is usually fine) but talk to your admin first.
4. Also if you get a lot of traffic then IIS logs will slowly fill up the C: drive. in C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\ you can clean up what you don't want.
5. bottom line is you need to know what's taking up the most space, and I find spacesniffer to be excellent for that http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/

Comment: Make sure the page file is not configured to be on the C drive, if it is then you can reconfigure it to be on a different drive as well.